# OSMNX does not recognize any attribute "AttributeError: module 'osmnx' has no attribute"

Tags: python, graph, networkx, attributeerror, osmnx

I have installed osmnx with conda config --prepend channels conda-forge, conda create -n ox --strict-channel-priority osmnx. When I am trying to use osmnx modules no one of modules is working, for example when I am using:

```py
import osmnx as ox
place_name = "Mitte, Hannover, Germany"
ox.graph_from_place(place_name, network_type='drive')
```

I am getting the error :

```py
AttributeError: module 'osmnx' has no attribute 'graph_from_place'
```

when I am using:

```py
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)
```

I am getting the error :

```py
AttributeError: module 'osmnx' has no attribute 'config'
```

and so on. No attribute is working

I also tried to use attributes according to https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#module-osmnx.graph but it also did not work with the same error:

```py
import osmnx as ox
place_name = "Mitte, Hannover, Germany"
ox.graph.graph_from_place(place_name, network_type='all_private')
```

```py
AttributeError: module 'osmnx' has no attribute 'graph'
```

The python version of the ox environment is 3.8.6 and Spyder(4.1.4).
Could you please help me to find the solutions for these errors?

Comment: Sounds like your installation did not work. Try removing the ox conda env, then reinstall.

Comment: Thank you, reinstalled but did not help.

Comment: In your code can you `print(ox)` and `print(ox.__version__)`. What do they show?

Comment: @gboeing for print(ox) shows the path to the python file:  print(ox)
<module 'osmnx' from 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\osmnx.py'>   for print(ox.__version__):
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-dd1889a6a322>", line 1, in <module>
    print(ox.__version__)

AttributeError: module 'osmnx' has no attribute '__version__'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a file named `osmnx.py` on your Desktop and are importing that rather than the installed module. Rename that file.

Comment: Thank you very much, could not imagine that it can be a reason.